# How to set a custom useragent string in Mojo::UserAgent

Tags: perl, user-agent, mojo, mojolicious

We have a bunch of code built around Mojo::UserAgent and migrating to MojoX::UserAgent is not quite an option. I wonder if there is a way to get/set user agent string in Mojo::UserAgent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`name`](http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious-3.42/lib/Mojo/UserAgent.pm#name) accessor:

```
my $name = $ua->name;
$ua->name('Mozilla/5.0');
```

(Note that in the 4.x release, the name accessor has been removed)

Answer (score 10):

The current (Mojo 4.5) way is:

```
# Change name of user agent
$ua->transactor->name('MyUA 1.0');
```

See CPAN documentation [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent#transactor).